# React - useState não atualiza

Tags: javascript, react

Tenho um useState de Fruits e um dropdown que chama uma função ao ser selecionado, passando o ID do item.

```
const [selectedFruit, setSelectedFruit] = useState<string>();

          <Dropdown
            id="dd"
            titleText="dd fruit"
            label='Selecione um item'
            items={fruitList}
            onChange={item => handleSelect(String(item.selectedItem?.id))}
          />
```

Após isso, na função que é chamada ao selecionar um item no DropDown eu chamo o setState,passando o valor recebido para ele.

```
const handleSelect = (fruit: string) => {

setSelectedFruit(fruit);

}
```

Após isso, quando tento chamar o state em uma função que está abaixo, me retorna sempre o valor antigo, e ao tentar de novo me vem o valor certo (ou seja, vem com delay, nunca no tempo certo)
A função que está logo abaixo dessa é:

```
handleMixFruits() {

console.log(selectedFruit);

}
```

não consigo entender esse bug, pois já fiz muita coisa parecida e sempre deu certo, alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Comment: O componente [`Dropdown`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/#dropdown-props) não possui o evento `onChange`. Em seu lugar use o evento `onSelect` que é acionado quando um item de menu é selecionado. `onSelect={handleSelect}`

Comment: O erro persiste mas obg pela dica, vou passar a usar assim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o amigo acima informou, utilize o `React.useEffect` para executar uma função sempre que alguma ou states específicos forem alterados.

```
React.useEffect(() => {

   console.log(selectedFruit)

}, [selectedFruit])
```

No código acima por exemplo, sempre que o state de selectedFruit for modificado, ele vai rodar a função vinculada a ele. Caso você faça o useEffect sem o parâmetros com o array de states:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    
       console.log(selectedFruit)
    
})
```

Ele vai rodar essa função toda vez que qualquer state dentro desse componente for alterado.

Comment: Me ajudou demais! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Acho que tá tentando problema de async, lendo uma propriedade antes de ela ter sido definida.

Dá uma olhada no hook `useEffect`, ele vai adicionar um evento que tu definir (console.log, por ex) quando o ciclo de vida do componente for disparado, e só vai acontecer depois de realmente ter sido modificado.

Comment: Então, eu acho que a propriedade está chegando atrasada na propriedade mesmo, porque a função não tem o comportamento esperado, com o console.log no useEffect ele realmente traz o valor correto , mas na função chega o valor anterior (com atraso)